# Eclipse maven with Jenkins integration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I wanted to use the inbuilt maven of my eclipse to integrate with jenkines.

can some please suggest how to do that when i try to put the m2[C:\Users\HP.m2\repository] path in Jenkins and try to build it gives me error.

Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\new_job
ERROR: A Maven installation needs to be available for this project to be built.Either your server has no Maven installations defined, or the requested Maven version does not exist.
ERROR: Step ‘Publish TestNG Results’ failed: A Maven installation needs to be available for this project to be built.Either your server has no Maven installations defined, or the requested Maven version does not exist.
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: so DO you have maven installed on this machine? What happens when you do maven in the Command Prompt?

is MAVEN_HOME variable populated?

Comment: If your job type is FreeStyle, you need use `Execute windows cmd` Build Step to run maven cmd, if job type is Maven, you need to config Maven installations in menu: Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins from Jenkins UI/console

Comment: #Devinda, yes Maven_Home and m2 path has been configured correctly as i can run the project from cmd. but still facing the same issue.

Comment: It's very strange to run Jenkins on the same box that you run Eclipse, but Jenkins has to be configured with a Maven installation. It's not good enough to just install Maven on the box.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

You need to use a command line Maven for Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks you all, i have installed maven separately now after so many attempts of using the inbuilt eclipse maven. but i'm still getting the same error.